# How to show only one horizontal line for a specific axis value in R chart - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a R visualisation in Power BI and looking at having only 1 grid line where the horizontal axis value crosses the axis value at 1.

I am not good with words and  not sure if I have explained it well in words.  Please see the screenshots below to get a better understanding of what I want to achieve.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

First screenshot is from Excel where I was able to do it and I want to replicate the same in the R chart (second screenshot)

[image: Excel visual]

[image: R visual]

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(unique(dataset), aes(x = reorder(Condition, Rate), y = Rate)) +

labs(x = "Condition")+

geom_point(size = 5, stroke = 0, shape = 18, colour="brown") +

geom_point() + geom_line() +

geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = LL, ymax = UL), width=.2, position=position_dodge(.9), colour="brown", alpha=0.6, size=.7) +

theme_bw()+
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank()) +

theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=90, hjust = 1))+

theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10))
```

Comment: Have you tried `+ geom_hline(yintercept = 1)`?

Comment: Thank you very much.  I have included + geom_hline(yintercept = 1) in my code and it worked. The additional code about changing the colour of the line is wonderful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `p` is your original `ggplot` object

step 1: remove the original `x` axis

```
 p + theme(axis.line.x = element_blank(), 
           axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
           axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
     labs(x = '') -> p1
```

step 2: add a line at `1`

```
 p1 + geom_hline(yintercept = 1, color = "black")
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. The solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

As you have not provided any data, so I am using `iris` dataset. You can use the following code

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(unique(iris), aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Width)) +
  labs(x = "Condition")+
  geom_point(size = 5, stroke = 0, shape = 18, colour="brown") +
  geom_point() + geom_line() +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=90, hjust = 1))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10)) +
  geom_abline(slope=0, intercept=1,  col = "darkblue",lty=1,size = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. The solution works perfectly.